# Wireless is disabled by hardware switch (other seen solutions won't work)

Tags: networking, wireless, hardware, wifi-hardware-switch

I bought an old Lenovo T430s. It arrived with the airplane mode switched on, with the toggle grayed out. It says to "use hardware switch to turn off". So far I have tried:

1. Toggling the hardware switch on the side of the laptop - this doesn't do anything.
2. Resetting my BIOS to default settings.
3. Taking my battery out and restarting the laptop.
4. Fn + F5. This displays a message on screen saying "Hardware Aeroplane Mode".

rfkill list all:

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
```

So other solutions like adding something to the blacklist or rfkill unblock don't appear to work either. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Hard Blocked" indicates a hardware lockout.  Which means it's disabled on your system.  In your BIOS, do you have an option to disable/enable wifi?  I ask this because you can't unblock a hard block with rfkill or such.

Comment: I cannot see such an option. Under config > network, there is "Wake On LAN = [AC Only]", and "Ethernet LAN Option ROM = [Enabled]". But I cannot see anything else related to wifi

Comment: If the results for `rfkill list` don't change after moving the wifi switch(you do have to run `rfkill list` again) then the switch is bad and this isn't an Ubuntu issue but this video should fix https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yzAKcmlaH1M&ab_channel=SimonHayter